# How does this function get stored in my object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across a particular way of placing a function inside of a javascript object I don't quite understand. Typically, you would have something like:

```
var obj = {
 foo: function() {
   return 'bar';
  }

} //obj.foo() === 'bar'
```

However, I found that I can get the same thing with:

```
var obj = {
  foo() {
   return 'bar';
  }

} //obj.foo() === 'bar'
```

Is this just another way of declaring methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an ES2015 feature regarding to Method Definition.

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions
>   on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a
>   function assigned to the method's name.

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot. I got to read up more on ES2015 additions.